# Why does pm2 start my ghost blog in developement?

Tags: pm2, ghost

I am not able to understand why pm2 starts my ghost blog in developement instead of production.

I can run this 
`npm start --production` and everything is fine like I want it. But if I try to use pm2 
`pm2 start index.js` it starts my blog in developement which I don't want to. I must be blind but can not see in the docs how I can force pm2 to start in production mode.

I only have success starting the app with npm like this:
`npm start --production`

I tried with a config file `ecosystem.config.js` and to start it like this:

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` or

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production` but it seems to start in developement. Here is my config file.

`module.exports = {
    apps : [
      {
        name      : "asle",
        script    : "index.js",
        env: {
          COMMON_VARIABLE: "true"
        },
        env_production : {
          NODE_ENV: "production"
        }
      }
     ]
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ghost blog always runs in development mode by default. If you want to run it with pm2 in production use following command

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start index.js
```

You can also read in my blog post: https://drifts.io/how-to-setup-ghost-blog-on-vps/#step5installpm2processmanager

Also dont forget to use pm2 startup and  save to make sure it persistent over reboots.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create an ecosystem file to declare how you want to launch in production ? 
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

If yes can you show it ?

Comment: I listed my config file above. The strange thing is that I deleted all pm2 cache and ran the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production` and it is working now. But I really don't see why I have to have a config file when I have to specify --env production in the command to start it. Is it required to have a config file?